# Craft CMS Database Structure and Schema Schematics

Tags: database

Is there somewhere that we can find a the schematics of crafts database structure/schema. We  are looking into developing a database migration workflow between development and production environments.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Tools like Navicat and MySQL Workbench both have ways of [analyzing](http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/Does_Navicat_support_forward/reverse_engineering%3F) a [database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-data-modeling.html) and generate a schema map from it, so you can visualize the tables, foreign keys, etc.